# React-Native Different View for Landscape Mode ios and android

Tags: react-native

1. What is the recommended practice to create different layouts for
   small and large screens?
2. What is the method to detect the device screen size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.The recommended practice to create different layouts is to use [FlexBox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html), but if you cannot achieve this using FlexBox, you can use something like Dimensions.

2.There are a few methods to detect device screen size, the main one I've been using and have seen used is Dimensions. You can get the dimensions with Dimensions like so:

```
var {
...,
Dimensions
} = React;

var deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

<View style={{ width: deviceWidth }} />
```